# Plotting multiple matrices gnuplot

Tags: animation, matrix, gnuplot

I'm fairly new to gnuplot and I'm trying to see how my array varies with iterations of my program to debug, I would ideally like to be able to make an animation of the data.

Here's what my data looks like:

**'q=0'**

```
1 0 0 

0 1 1

1 1 0
```

**'q=1'**

```
1 0 0  
0 1 1  
0 1 0
```

and so on.

I tried using: plot `"matrix.dat"` index 0 matrix with image, just to plot the first matrix but I got `"Warning matrix contains missing or undefined values, Matrix does not represent a grid".`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem may be the comment lines.  When I used this version of your data file

```
1 0 0
0 1 1
1 1 0

1 0 0 
0 1 1 
0 1 0
```

plotting with `index` works.  To make an animation, you could create a series of .png files and [stitch them together with another application](http://www.gnuplotting.org/animation-gif/).  An example of the gnuplot code to make the .pngs would be:

```
set terminal png
do for [i=0:100] {
    set output sprintf('matrix%03.0f.png',i)
    plot 'data.dat' index i matrix with image
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, that's a great help.